# Parse Code from Text - Python

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am analyzing StackOverflow's dump file "Posts.Small.xml" using pySpark. I want to separate 'code block' from 'text' in a Row. A typical parsed row looks like:

```
            ['[u"<p>I want to use a track-bar to change a form\'s opacity.</p>&#xA;&#xA;
        <p>This is my code:</p>&#xA;&#xA;<pre><code>decimal trans = trackBar1.Value / 5000;&#xA;this.Opacity = trans;&#xA;</code></pre>&#xA;&#xA;
    <p>When I try to build it, I get this error:</p>&#xA;&#xA;<blockquote>&#xA;  <p>Cannot implicitly convert type \'decimal\' to \'double\'.
</p>&#xA;</blockquote>&#xA;&#xA;<p>I tried making <code>trans</code> a <code>double</code>, but then the control doesn\'t work.',
             '", u\'This code has worked fine for me in VB.NET in the past.',
             '\', u"</p>&#xA; When setting a form\'s opacity should I use a decimal or double?"]']
```

I've tried "itertools" and some python functions but couldn't get the result. 
My initial code to extract the above row is:

```
postsXml = textFile.filter( lambda line: not line.startswith("<?xml version=")
postsRDD = postsXml.map(............)
tokensentRDD = postsRDD.map(lambda x:(x[0], nltk.sent_tokenize(x[3])))
new = tokensentRDD.map(lambda x: x[1]).take(1)
a = ''.join(map(str,new))
b = a.replace("&lt;", "<")
final = b.replace("&gt;", ">")
nltk.sent_tokenize(final)
```

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the `code` contents by using XPath (the `lxml` library will help) and then extract the text content selecting everything else, for example:

```
import lxml.etree


data = '''<p>I want to use a track-bar to change a form's opacity.</p>
          <p>This is my code:</p> <pre><code>decimal trans = trackBar1.Value / 5000; this.Opacity = trans;</code></pre>
          <p>When I try to build it, I get this error:</p>
          <p>Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'double'.</p>
          <p>I tried making <code>trans</code> a <code>double</code>.</p>'''

html = lxml.etree.HTML(data)
code_blocks = html.xpath('//code/text()')
text_blocks = html.xpath('//*[not(descendant-or-self::code)]/text()')
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! It worked. could you please explain it briefly? I'm trying to learn

Comment: The `html` object created is a lxml object representing the whole HTML tree. By using lxml I can query this tree using XPath (learn more at http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp), which is a language to query XML nodes. The query I used is `//code/text()` which return the text for all `<code>` elements.

Comment: great! do you know how to print out the residual text_block from the above code?

Comment: You can use the following XPath: `//*[not(descendant-or-self::code)]/text()`, it'll select every node except `<code>` and will get its text. I've updated the code on the answer. If it completely answer your question please mark as so. :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will probably be to apply a regex to the text, matching tags '`' and '`'. That would enable you to find the code blocks. You don't say what you would do with them afterwards, though. So ...

```
from itertools import zip_longest

sample_paras = [
    """<p>I want to use a track-bar to change a form\'s opacity.</p>&#xA;&#xA;<p>This is my code:</p>&#xA;&#xA;<pre><code>decimal trans = trackBar1.Value / 5000;&#xA;this.Opacity = trans;&#xA;</code></pre>&#xA;&#xA;<p>When I try to build it, I get this error:</p>&#xA;&#xA;<blockquote>&#xA;  <p>Cannot implicitly convert type \'decimal\' to \'double\'. </p>&#xA;</blockquote>&#xA;&#xA;<p>I tried making <code>trans</code> a <code>double</code>, but then the control doesn\'t work.""",
    """This code has worked fine for me in VB.NET in the past.""",
    """</p>&#xA; When setting a form\'s opacity should I use a decimal or double?""",
]

single_block = " ".join(sample_paras)

import re
separate_code = re.split(r"</?code>", single_block)

text_blocks, code_blocks = zip(*zip_longest(*[iter(separate_code)] * 2))

print("Text:\n")
for t in text_blocks:
    print("--")
    print(t)

print("\n\nCode:\n")
for t in code_blocks:
    print("--")
    print(t)
```

Comment: I want to count the number of occurrences of each character in every row, length of the code, text and display the result in a DataFrame. Thanks a ton for the help!!

Comment: Regular expressions can be hard to understand and error prone. If we're talking about HTML/XML the best option would be using an specialized parser.